# What is the easiest way to reinstall 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

I've lost the thumbdrive that had the image on it. Is there some way to reinstall without one?

E: It's a reinstall over an existing ubuntu install. Windows issues really aren't all that relevant.

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall?

Comment: see [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) and [Guide How to re-install ubuntu keeping your data and settings](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057342)

Comment: I have a ca-certificates error I've been trying to fix for a month

Comment: Dumb  question- but what is 'ubuntuinstaller'? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** If you already have Ubuntu installed, then you should [follow this guide on how to reinstall in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057342).

1. Download Unetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
2. Run Unetbootin.
3. From the drop down menu under **Type:** select **Hard Disk**
4. Next select the **Diskimage**. Browse to the directory where you downloaded the iso file.
   [image: Unetbootin Interface]
5. Press **OK**.
6. Now restart your computer. Select **Unetbootin** when the menu appears where it shows your operating system. It should look something like this:
   [image: BIOS Unetbotin]
7. Afterwards, simply proceed with the installation as normally.
8. Now you should be able to install Ubuntu without a USB or a CD.

Another alternative that you can do is use your Android phone. There is an application on the Google Play Store titled DriveDroid that you can get [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en). The interface will assist you to get Ubuntu on your machine. You will need to have root to use this application.

Comment: I already have ubuntu installed but I don't have a disk drive. Can I just follow your instructions?