# What is the easiest way to reinstall 14.04 LTS? Redux

Tags: 14.04

I've tried this, none of it works.

[What is the easiest way to reinstall 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661997/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reinstall-14-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment953607_661997)

So far I've: Made a bootable USB, made a bootable hard drive partition, neither will boot.

This is not a dual boot, this is not a windows machine, I do not need to save files or usernames. I've followed every direction I can find and nothing. I have an ongoing issue with ca-certificates that has never been solved, and I'm just trying to get a clean image at this point.

Booting off of a USB formatted with Unetbootin does nothing. The grub menu only has the current install.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop), boot from that and install onto your hard drive, wiping out any existing non-working partitions.