# Ubuntu re-installing everytime I restart my computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'll just jump right into it.

Just to give a sort of run down: I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto my windows 7 desktop so I can dual boot it.

So I was on YouTube looking up videos on how to install Ubuntu onto my hard drive without using a USB/CD. I came across this one video where the guy downloaded an installer and it automatically set up everything with a couple clicks. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8p-jzAl6dos&index=28&list=WL)

When I followed the download link he had listed in the video description this is what I got: http://prntscr.com/9274l5

When I double clicked the icon it asked me to insert a disk into my computer to burn it. At this point I was really confused because this looked nothing like the video. So I search up a couple sources until I come across this: [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

I downloaded the program which the best answer had suggested. I then enter the file into it and put it on my C: drive. I reboot my computer and sure enough it comes with the option to boot up Windows 7 or Unetbootin. So I enter the Unetbootin option and everything loads up after 5-10 minutes. I start to try downloading Java and signing into my firefox account and notice my sound isn't coming through my headphones. I then tweak a couple things and restart my computer to see if the changes I made will take effect. But when I enter the Unetbootin option it just reinstalls Ubuntu all over again.

I'm really confused since everywhere I look people who are having the same problem as me are using USB/CDs to boot up Ubuntu and from what I understand I have it on my hard drive already.

If someone could give me a hand that would be great!

P.S: If what I described is too confusing to understand I could take some pictures of the boot-up screen and post them.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you reboot and select unetbootin, you are asking to reinstall. Select a different option at boot - hopefully Ubuntu is an option, if it really got installed.