# how do i remove a frugal install from C:\

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I tried installing ubuntu using the instructions here: [answer with 32 votes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how). unfortunately, it didn't work out well for my windows 10. I might be a bit naive but I blindly followed the instructions provided in the pictures, i.e. on unetbootin, I chose hard drive and C:\ and didn't specify anything else other than what was indicated in the instructions.

When I rebooted, I didn't get a menu asking me which operating system to choose, whether it's windows 10 or unetbootin. Even pressing F12 did not help.

So I am giving up for now and I will just wait until I can find a USB. My only problem now is that my drive C:\ is called "Install Ubuntu (C:)" with the Ubuntu icon. I am wondering if there's anyway I can revert it back to what it originally was which is simply Drive C:.

Thanks a lot for your help!

(I basically have the same problem as [this person](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231522) but no solution was given.)

Comment: I also feel like my start up is slowed down because of this...

Comment: the instructions you copied are what's known as a frugal install. It piggybacks off the existing OS's bootloader and installs the files for the live environment inside the existing partition.Never done one nor know if windows 10 is supported. You may get a better response changing your question to something like "how do i remove a frugal install from C:\"

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and failed as well, what you basically need to do is very simple. Just launch unetbootin and you'll get a prompt that says "Unetbootin is already installed. Uninstall?" Click yes and all linux files will be deleted.