# How do I re-install Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)?

Tags: upgrade

I have a Samsung notebook. I want to re-install Ubuntu on it, but I don't have a Ubuntu [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD).

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Can you install Ubuntu without a live CD/USB reinstall or freshly installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at:

[Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

and at the official installation guide, they have a part about your situation under installation with no CD:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

To the editors: this should probably be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: yes there are net installs not sure for ubuntu but there should be. they still require a download but not of the ubuntu install until you have booted into the installation process.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` merely reinstalls the Unity Desktop Environment, not Ubuntu itself.

If you want to completely reinstall Ubuntu, you will need either a DVD or USB stick that is at least 4GB (2GB will probably work, but use something higher to be safe). There is a network boot option, where you can install Ubuntu from a network source, but that requires that your computer can boot from the network, and you have to create some complex server setup. The easiest way to install Ubuntu is using a DVD, but a USB stick isn't hard either.

If you want to reinstall Ubuntu, you have to have some sort of bootable media. However, you can create your own LiveDVD, and if you don't have a disc, you can create a LiveUSB.

***DVD Method***

1. Download the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Once the ISO is finished downloading, insert a blank DVD.
3. Right click the ISO and select the `Write to Disc...` option.
4. Select the DVD drive in the dropdown and click `Burn`.

Reboot and boot from the DVD.

***USB Method***

If your computer doesn't have a DVD writer or doesn't have a DVD drive at all, use this method.

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO from the link above.
2. Insert your 4GB USB stick.
3. Download [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) and open it.
4. Browse to the download ISO and select the USB drive in the repsective menus.
5. Click the `Burn`, `Next`, or `Done` button (not sure what the name is).

Reboot and boot into the USB stick.

Comment: Ubuntu itself recommends against "tools like UNetbootin which alter the image". https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s03.html