# Ubuntu installation on Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

I recently installed elementary os thinking it was a relatively good operating system... However I've been mainly disappointed as I use public hotspots quite a lot and I can't actually connect to them on elementary so here's my question how do I install Ubuntu on Elementary OS. I also have a few limitations:
- No CD-Drivd
- No USB Stick

Is this possible or do I need to buy a USB?

Just to clarify I'm installing Ubuntu over a Linux OS not a Windows OS

Comment: Do it the same way as you installed eos. And I doubt that there will be any difference in wifi.

Comment: I had a memory stick then... I don't have one now :/ and what do you mean about the wifi? I only want to use BTWifi

Comment: So the easiest way is to get a USB flash drive. I do not know what is "BTWifi", but the wireless drivers are same in both distros. You probably need to install a driver.

Comment: I can connect to other wifi just fine it's because the hotspot doesn't have a password but requires you to sign in on a website, however it won't connect to it to let me access the sign in website :( I will look into getting a usb today

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

Comment: Notice how your question is an XY question: something in Elementary doesn't work so I'll install Ubuntu to fix it.