# Unable to boot ubuntu after installation(dual boot with win 7)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I had win 7 on my laptop. My cd drive and usb drive does not work. so I downloaded iso file of ubuntu 14 and installed ubootnetin(I  read in the internet that using this I can install ubuntu along with my win 7) So, then I installed ubuntu in a new partition(20 GB) and swap area (new partition-unallocated space-10 GB). After going through the process and successfully installing ubuntu, I rebooted my laptop. After rebooting, I had two options 1)windows 2)ubootnetin. If I choose ubootnetin,  it again starts the same ubuntu installation process. I am unable to load ubuntu. Kindly help.
I know for sure that ubuntu is installed in my laptop, when I go in win7, the c drive has name"install ubuntu" and ubuntu symbol.

Comment: Hmm. Something obviously got messed up with the partitioning.

Comment: Related. Maybe it can give you some pointers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The program you seem to be using is called Unetbootin. It is only used to create a bootable USB stick, which can then be used to install Ubuntu. I think you might have accidentally tried to make your Windows partition a bootable Ubuntu stick. Can you still boot Windows and use it like before? If so, use Unetbootin to create a bootable usb stick, install Ubuntu again, then remove the usb stick (!) and reboot. U should see a Menu where you can choose between Windows and Ubuntu.

EDIT: Sorry, i didn't see that your usb does not work. In that case, this won't help you. Do none of your usb ports work? Do they not work at all or just under windows?

Comment: I am a newbie to ubuntu. Yes, I can still boot windows and use it like before. Yes, none of my usb ports work.(was working fine 2 weeks ago then suddenly stopped working.) They do not work in windows, not sure about other os.

Comment: I read that without using cd drive/usb drive, you can dual boot using Ubootnetin.     Is there any way for me to install ubuntu along with windows(without cd drive/ usb drive)?

Comment: The only way i can think of is to remove the hard drive from your laptop, put it in some other pc and install ubuntu on it. Then put it back in, it should work

Comment: I don't know how this is supposed to work, and i think you read it wrong. You can use Unetbootin to create a usb stick, with which you can then install ubuntu side by side with windows. Can you please provide a link to the article where u supposedly read that.

Comment: this is the link where I read that.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how

Comment: Okay, i found the article you were referring to. Can we pls [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37449/help-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: In the chat I can only read your messages.I cannot join it because I have only 7 points and I need min 20 points to chat. Can you give me your gmail address or any other social media to chat?