# PC FIx / ubtuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I installed Ubuntu onto my Hard drive using the method here: [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

My intention was to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu. I needed more space for the OS, so I messed with the partitioning etc.

I wanted to erase Windows 7 for it. I erased all partitions and created one for home, another for something else and the main one following a video which I can't find and don't remember well. It said reboot to complete installation, and I did.

But now when I boot up my pc it seems I erased my operating system and it won't let me boot Ubuntu, it just shows me the keys i can press for bios etc and after that it just goes to a black screen with a flashing cursor top left that's not interactive.

When I press F9 for diagnosics it says i pass everything but Boot test and it gives me an error code that is "BIOHD3" and it gives me a warning saying no active partitions. Now my brother loaded up ubuntu on one of his flash drives for me and booted it off of that. It has mostly errors as shown below.

I do not have a Windows recovery disk either and I just do not know what to do. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Reinstall again. This time, just install Ubuntu without any manual partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Run the install "disk" but don't install.  Use the "Try Ubuntu" button and load the Live Image.  Once loaded run the partition editor (GParted).  From here you can delete the current partitions; don't create any new partitions.  Restart the computer, but this time you should install Ubuntu - again, following the prompts.  At the disk partition request select "Use the whole (full?) disk" and also the LVM option.  This should sort out any problems and enable a clean installation.   Other disks installed should be clean and not partitioned until after the install.

Comment: You dont understand. I dont have a disc but i have a flash drive that of which i tried to boot from ubuntu, after my failed install with dual booting it with my hdd. I tried the ash drive with ubuntu on it and when i go to an option it shows up with a page like this       http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4X2j.jpg

Comment: It wont let me boot into any os or anything

Comment: Kernel panics have a multitude of causes.  this page might of help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0?rq=1  : basically a fresh download of the Ubuntu OS onto the flashdrive and try and do the install from there.