# Erasing When I Restart

Tags: unetbootin

I recently got Ubuntu 16.04 and I like it so far. I got it by UNetbootin, and installed it on a Windows Vista computer so I can see what Ubuntu is like.
Everything works fine, but I have a problem. Every time I restart my computer, UNetbootin resets the whole OS and all my files are deleted. I got them back, but I don't want this to  happen again!

If someone would give me a solution that would be great,

Thanks!

Here's the link to the site I visited: [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

The computer I'm using isn't very new, and I can't boot from a USB and the CD reader is broken!

Comment: Did you remember to give it space to preserve files across reboots?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Oh! On the tutorial it didn't specify that! Is there any way I can do that without erasing all my files?

Comment: No, it has to be done at installation. I'll write the instructions as an answer entry below.

Comment: How much more space would you recommend I add?

Comment: That's up to you and how much data you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

When using UNetbootin to install Ubuntu (and only Ubuntu), you first have to specify an an amount of disk space to preserve files across reboots. There's an entry for this on the dialog box.

Comment: How much more space would you recommend I add?

Comment: @Lowbatman All of the remaining space left by the OS, not like you need empty space anyways.

Comment: I tried twice, once with 185 megabytes, and once with the most you can put: 9999 MB, which is about 10 GB. when I rebooted after both the same thing happened as before, can I put more space, or is it a completely different problem?