# Install ubuntu without CD or USB on a Macbook

Tags: 16.04, mac

I know this question has already been asked but I didn't find any answer to my problem or working tutorial.

I'm on a 2010 white macbook and I would like to install ubuntu as my main OS. I have no usb stick or CD, but I have an external hard drive with all my data. I don't want to lose it. I tried to partition it but I can't boot on it.

I'm on Mac OS Sierra and I don't know how to do !

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: You could try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how), but I make sure to have backups and be very careful when re partitioning your hard drive. I recommend you just purchase a cheap 4GB USB and install- it's completely worth the hassle.

Comment: I agree with Patrick Negus: buy a cheap 4GB USB pendrive and install! I would add that it is risky to install an operating system, so you should be sure that you have backed up all your personal data to the external hard disk drive before you start partitioning and installing.