# [NO CD / USB]How to install linux on an unallocated space without

Tags: dual-boot, gnome

how can i install linux (gnome) on an unallocated soace on my hard drive without cd/usb , because i have windows 10 and i want to make a dual boot . I made this unallocated space an ex4 partition whats next?

Comment: Look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how