# could you analyse this 'UNetbootin' error -- can't boot from usb - so using 'UNetbootin'

Tags: boot, live-usb

basic overview of problem:

**goal:** trying to install a new linux os (any working one is fine)
**key problem:** the laptop does not boot from usb

**laptop** = lenovo u310 (none of the reset / bios methods work)
**os** = mint 18.1 (completely dysfunctional, crashes and freeze randomly like a min after booting the os)

---

on 'GNU GRUB' version 2.02~'

it has the option 'UNetbootin'

when i select this and press enter

---

it shows a black screen, black screen says:

> running early hook [udev]
> starting version 232

other things

then

> mounting 'dev/disk/by-label/' to 'run/miso/bootmnt'

then stuff

> ERROR: '/deve/disk/by-label/' device did not show up after 30 secondds...'
>
> Falling back to interactive prompt
> You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
>
> sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
>
> [rootfs ]#

where i can type something

---

im very new to linux so please explain what should be done and why? to solve this problem

Comment: We can help with Ubuntu and official derivatives. We cannot with Mint because its' not Ubuntu or an official derivative). Anyway, you don't use Unetbootin because it is unreliable and known to not work with most UEFI based machines such as yours. You want to proceed according to this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: unetbootin is unreliable.. well what are exactly the other options? unetbootin seemed like the only thing that was left. the things on that page you linked was tried in the past and nothing worked

Comment: *unetbootin seemed like the only thing that was left.* I hope you aren't expecting to be taken seriously after this... But it doesn't matter anyway because OFF TOPIC. Also, for future reference, the "tried *everything* to no avail" is a well known and frown upon trope we're all familiar with and it doesn't work. Question like that are usually ignored or closed as "unclear".

Comment: is it 100% for sure that a external cd drive with a iso in it would auto-boot?
 
none of the startup hotkeys works. without changing bios or anything?  since none of this is accessible

Comment: With an ISO in it certainly not. The ISO file is to be burned like that, not as a DVD-ROM with th ISO file inside. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0 Many other programs work the same way. The tutorial is just a reference.

Comment: so is there no non-bios method to this problem at all? is there any solutions outside of having to access bios?

Comment: would https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how

work?

or would it just lead to the same error or some similiar type of problem?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Wubi is no longer developed, it never was intended for permanent installations and can't possibly work in any Windows 8 or newer.

Comment: the os is mint 18.1, not win8 or newer. since i cant fix it, im just gonna get the linux mint working. what's all the diagnostics programs to run typically on a laptop? 

ill just run those diagnoistics and see if it says anything

mint doesnt update

some error, long

Comment: You're just talking nonsense now, clearly you aren't understanding a word of what I'm trying to explain and it's also becoming clear that you conveniently ignore that MINT IS OFF TOPIC HERE therefore nobody will answer and the question itself should have been closed as long time ago. Over and out.