# Boot ubuntu without USB or CD

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

I have Windows and I want to boot Ubuntu from iso, but I haven't any USB or CD.
Can I put bootable files to disk part or how to make this?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)