# Install ubuntu from a hdd partition, no external USB at hand

Tags: boot, system-installation

Is there any way to install Ubuntu from within Windows 10?

I've tried to use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) but when I boot from my boot manager I get a grub console (I guess that's what it is) or when I go into **Windows boot manager** it gets me to some kind of error then my only option is to press enter to go into back into the **Windows boot manager**.

Comment: The 25-step (!) UEFI instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/484456/197910 from Raphael https://askubuntu.com/users/119531/raphael explain how, but if you have a DVDR handy, the solution below is easier. Picking up a 4GB or larger flash drive and using the Rufus http://rufus.ie Windows open source app is easiest of all.

Comment: It may be possible to install without a USB drive, but it's easier to go buy a cheap 4GB pendrive than waste hours on end trying to figure out how to do it. Also if you already tried UNetbootin and didn't manage try other possible utilities like rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DVDR drive and a blank disk? You could burn an Ubuntu LiveDVD (AKA 'LiveCD') Ubuntu Tutorials has instructions to [create it in Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0). Would that be acceptable?

In a Windows web browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE, et cetera) go to [Ubuntu's download page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and pick the version of Ubuntu you want. Versions 18.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, and 19.04 are supported here. I would suggest 18.04 LTS since it will be supported until 2023.

If you want to use a different desktop environment for Ubuntu Desktop, those are [downloaded from here](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).

Also, download the SHA-512 checksum. Once the downloads finish, use [CertUtil](https://www.nextofwindows.com/5-ways-to-generate-and-verify-md5-sha-checksum-of-any-file-in-windows-10) which is part of Windows 10 to verify the download was not corrupted.

[Burn the DVD](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1) (and we use DVD instead of CD because you can't fit all of a complete Ubuntu installer onto a CD any more) in Windows by right-clicking on the ISO file of the Ubuntu installer and choose **Burn Disk Image**. Once burned, reboot your PC and follow the [Ubuntu installation instruction](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#2)s.