# How to live boot ubuntu with ubuntu as host OS without usb?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I have Ubuntu 18.04 as my host OS. I want to live boot with an Ubuntu 18.04 iso to change my disk space using gparted without using USB.

I followed the steps that are required using unetbootin as described in the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/484456/719469.

However I do not get any option called unetbootin in my grub menu when I boot my system using BIOS. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you adjust the boot order in the BIOS to have the USB drive before the disk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Even though the examples are old, I believe this page will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Answer (score 0):

Wubi's [home page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/)  has not been updated in five years, and it points to a non-existent URL at Ubuntu.com . I don't see any support for 18.04 there or at its [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/wubi). I suggest you use a [LiveDVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) instead.