# Can I install ubuntu on my laptop from Windows 10 without a USB or DVD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

The reason that I cannot use a usb or cd is because the 'xHCL Compliant Host Controller' is not working on my laptop. I have tried every methods I could find, even resetting my laptop to factory settings as a last resort. But, to reset my laptop, I got rid of my Ubuntu partition and I've been looking for a solution to get it back.

I have tried Unetbootin as I've seen recommended online, but I get this error from the Windows boot manager while trying to boot using unetbootin:
note: i was trying to install ubuntu 20.04 on my disk using ubuntu, as shown here:
[How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb..). However this was to dual boot with Windows 7, and I have Windows 10 so maybe that is the problem?

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. to fix the problem:
  
  1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disk, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.

    Files: \ubnldr.mbr
    
    Status: 0xc000007b

    Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or 
          contains errors
```

If anyone knows whether it is feasible to install ubuntu on my laptop without a USB or DVD, or if you have any ideas on how to make it work, let me know!

my laptop:
ASUS UX330UAK
Windows version: 10.0.18363 Build 18363
BIOS mode: UEFI
Let me know what other information is needed!

NOTE: I see a lot of discussions about this topic where people just say "just use a USB" but that is NOT possible in my case, and I can't use a DVD either (I don't have a slot for it). Similarly, SD cards also do not work. I am not looking for a solution to fix my USB driver (or whatever it is that isn't working) since I spent two days in the guts of google trying all the different solutions, I doubt there is a solution I haven't tried. Sending my laptop to the manufacturer is not an option as I need it everyday for classes and work.

Comment: Did you use the UEFI instructions?  Win 7 was usually legacy and Win 10 UEFI(usually).  Need to use UEFI instructions.

Comment: @crip659 I did it until step 13 where it asks to "Select the newly created partition and right-click on it. Select Create Partition from context menu."... I do not get that option on my PC (either on disk manager or EaseUS). The only option I get is create simple volume, but I don't know if it does the same thing, but I know it doesn't give me the same options as in the tutorial.

Comment: Fast google search says simple volume made on dynamic disk, which you don't want.  You know if your Windows is on basic or dynamic partition?  I am thinking it might be better to put Ubuntu in a VM.

Comment: @crip659 I don't know whether Windows is on dynamic or basic partition, I've googled for a way to find it but I couldn't find anything. I didn't know what to google to help with my case, which is why "fast google search" doesn't help me here. running on a VM is an option but I prefer the option to dual booth / just run Ubuntu when I'm done with my windows partition

Comment: Windows disk manager should tell.  Dynamic partitions give Ubuntu trouble with installing.  Changing would probably be more trouble than what you want to deal with.

Comment: Link for installing on dynamic disks, but without USB, would just for info.  https://superuser.com/questions/335872/how-to-install-linux-on-a-dynamic-disk-without-losing-the-disk-configuration

Comment: @crip659 That is useful, Thanks! I'll explore these options as soon as I get the chance!

Answer (score 2):

### GRUB2 for Windows

You can download the Ubuntu ISO to a partition on your HDD.

You can install GRUB2 for Windows: https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/files/

You can boot the Ubuntu ISO using GRUB2 for Windows and install Ubuntu to the laptop.

**GRUB Menuentry:**

```
  menuentry "ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" {
     set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
     loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject maybe-ubiquity nopersistent
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
```

Prepare the space for Ubuntu install on your HDD using Windows Disk Management before proceeding.

Backup your disk before proceeding.

Boot the ISO and install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows runs in.

I have not tried this yet my self, but it seems reasonable based on first principles.

Please let us know if it works or not, this question is asked a lot in Ask Ubuntu and all the answers are obsolete.

More info: https://sourceforge.net/p/grub2win/discussion/search/?q=boot+iso&page=1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to work with Ubuntu but here is what I have done with Windows before. I have installed Windows on an HDD on one machine. Then I disconnected the HDD and put it on a different machine and it would work. So I guess you could detach your HDD/SSD from your laptop put it into a stationary PC, install Ubuntu there and put the HDD/SSD back. Should be easy.

Comment: Easy if OP has access to another PC, which he might not.

Comment: @crip659 True. But still an option, right?

Comment: A better answer would try to not use something the OP might not have.

Comment: That's a viable option, thanks! I'll have to do more reasearch to see how to connect an HDD to another device and all that, but otherwise it should do the trick if I can't get anything else to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install **Ubuntu** in virtual machine?

If not, it's very useful to install **Ubuntu** or any other *OS* into a virtual machine like ***Virtualbox*** if you want to work in external *OS* in the same PC or Laptop.

So, to start installing it, go to [Virtualbox Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Then, go to ubuntu and try to install `.ova` format. This will be beneficial if you want to install **Ubuntu** onto **Windows OS**.