# How to install Lubuntu when there is no "boot from usb" option in the BIOS?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mount, lubuntu

I am trying to install lubuntu on a ASUS EeeBook X205TA

I got lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso on another computer, it has the correct sha256sum.

I used "Startup Disk Creator" on Kubuntu to create a bootable usb.

Then I discovered that this notebook had a stupid BIOS. The only boot option was "Windows boot manager" or "disabled". It has no CD drive but it has 2 usb ports. Still, even with "Secure Boot" disabled there was no option to boot from usb.

Instead, there is a utility inside Windows 10, called "WinFlash". It offers 2 options : download the boot file from ASUS web site or open it.

Of course, my live usb stick has no iso file. I decided to remove the bootable stuff and to copy the iso file on it. Impossible.

```
umount /dev/sdb1

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/disk
mount: /media/disk: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.

/media/kube$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/disk
mount: /media/disk: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected.
```

I've done many installs of various flavours of Ubuntu. It's the first time I'm so much stuck. Please help.

Comment: I used an eeepc to test Lubuntu 18.04.5 (ie. `asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated), wireless RT2790`) and whilst yes I find that device a pain to get it to boot, hitting ESC during its execution of POST causes the eeepc to ask what device to boot, where I just selected the thumb-drive.

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  then write using a *tested* method?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview   FYI: I also have some devices I test with that require the respective key that causes the device to boot an external device (eg. thumb-drive) to be held down when device is off... device turns itself on on holding key ~2 secs

Comment: Plop boot manager installed to floppy disk, CD, or a corner of the HDD, will allow you to boot a USB: https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html, If you have Windows on the EBook you can uses UUI to install Ubuntu Live to a partition of the HDD and install Ubuntu using that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299828/can-i-install-ubuntu-20-10-or-20-04lts-on-dual-boot-with-windows-10-without-usb/1299969#1299969