# dual-boot-window-with-ubuntu-using-unetbootin-in-other-then-c-drive

Tags: software-installation

I watched a lot of videos that how to dual boot with ubuntu using Unetbootin but on the hard drive section there is only of option to select C: drive Even I have other drives too so is it possible to use another driver or not if not why. why there is only one option for C: drive only

ubuntu[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3PGU.png)

Comment: This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The C:\ option is for **Frugal install**. This allows Ubuntu Live to be installed to your hard drive for use in installing Full Ubuntu to that drive. - I have not had success with a UNetbootin Frugal install in many years. - It is easiest to install Ubuntu using a Live USB. If you can not access a Live USB, you can use a smart phone, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1330229/43926.  - If want to install Ubuntu Live to another hard drive see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1333112/43926. - You can also use Universal USB Installer to install Ubuntu without a USB: https://askubuntu.com/a/1299969/43926.

Comment: You can also boot your installer ISO from Windows using GRUB2 for Windows: https://askubuntu.com/a/1290304/43926