# Boot from USB (not Live ISO)

Tags: grub2, usb

I can't get my Ubuntu installation to boot up. As an alternative, is it possible to install GRUB2 on a USB device, then boot up using that, then unplug the USB device once Ubuntu is running? So I'm not wanting to install Ubuntu on the USB drive, or use a Live USB ISO, but instead just use the USB to facilitate booting.

Update:
This is an Ubuntu 20:10 installation, the laptop is a core i3 m370, 2 core, 4gb ram

Update: things attempted to get system to boot:

Installed from iso dvd
Reinstalled from iso

Swapped harddrive for new harddrive, and reinstalled

Ran fsck from live dvd

Installed boot-repair, it tells me to disable bios compatibility in my firmware, enable efi and try again. This is an old laptop and had no efi bios options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb)

Comment: What you want is very specific to hardware, some hardware will boot any device, others have specific devices they will load *boot* code from (ie. higher restrictions in order to provide greater security).  If you can't get your Ubuntu system to boot, provide some details any maybe we can help (did you verify your ISO, verify your write to install media?).  Yes you can boot a *live* system *toram*

Comment: Think it would be better/easier to find why your Ubuntu is not booting up, then to try odd work arounds.

Comment: I have a separate post asking that very question, but not getting anywhere with that, hence asking here about other options

Comment: For the record I can use a live CD to boot into the try it now option.

Comment: Would add your computer specs to your question/s.  Some have odd bios that need somethings to be disabled/enabled for booting Linux.  This info might give someone enough info to help, also the Ubuntu version you are using.  With boot-repair asking about EFI, just wondering if your installed Ubuntu as UEFI instead of legacy.  Is this a dual boot setup?

Comment: Added thanks, single boot. I didn't see an option to install uefi/legacy during installation? Is that an option when installing via dvd?

Comment: I do what you are asking, I used GParted to copy/paste a Ubuntu partition from one HDD to my Windows drive. I did not want to mess with my Windows bootloader so I plugged in a Full install USB, booted it and ran `sudo update-grub`. This added Ubuntu from the Windows computer to the USB's grub menu. Now when I want to boot Ubuntu on the Windows computer, I plug in the Full install USB and boot using it's grub. For a quick way to make a Full install USB see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried this, but got the same problem as above, where my laptop won't recognise the usb device as a valid boot device. Must be a legacy mode issue, just can't find any legacy options anywhere.

Comment: Know if USB has boot flag/check mark on it.  Legacy is what it is usually called by us, MBR is what it might be called by computer, couple other names also I think.

Comment: I've got this working by putting 18.04 on there. When using Rufus it gives bios/uefi as an option for 18.04, but only uefi for 20.10

Comment: Rufus works good for me with 20.04, I know 20.10 works with Etcher.