# BOOT from ISO using EasyBCD

Tags: boot, iso, easybcd

I am trying to use EasyBCD to boot from an ISO file without any discs or sticks and I get this error..

***/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found***

Do you have any ideas?

- OS: windows 10 ver 2004
- ISO: ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
- downloaded from ubuntu.com and verified. works fine on VirtualBox and USB sticks.

Comment: Have you verified the ISO is valid (that error can occur on invalid media/corrupted ISO)

Comment: It's downloaded from ubuntu.com and verified. I can use it to boot from a stick and it works fine on VirtualBox too..

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sr0 normally points to the CD drive, and Ubuntu mounts it to use some data that is stored on the boot ISO. When you add a new entry with EasyBCD and boot it, Windows directly loads the file (which means that the CD drive is empty), which means that Ubuntu can't find the data and thus fails to load.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any ideas about how to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to boot without a USB stick, but you could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb). Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Another note: don't use UNetBootin's hard drive install option if you don't know what you're doing. Actually, don't use it at all. I read the UNetBootin docs carefully several times and it still didn't work for me. Just get a USB stick or some other type of removable media, or use a VM like VirtualBox.