# is it possible to install ubuntu without a CD or a USB drive?

Tags: system-installation, 21.10

I wonder if it's possible to install Ubuntu without CD or USB flash drive because I can't use any.

My laptop's keyboard doesn't work properly so I'm using one with USB and my laptop has only two USB ports and one of them doesn't work with keyboard and USB flash drive(but works well with a mouse, that's another problem) because of this I need to use USB drive and keyboard same time but I can't.

I tried using Unetbootin but it gives me an error when booting, that ubnldr.mbr file is missing.
I also tried a lot of other ways but none of them worked,  for example, I created and then formated a new drive with FAT32 and copied contents of the iso file in it but after booting up my laptop it didn't work.

I'm using Windows 10. I have seen somewhere in ther internet that ubnldr.mbr file is missing error is caused by secure-boot but I have disabled it.

Finally, my question is:
**Is it possible to install ubuntu without a USB flash drive or CD and if it's, how?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb). Yes it is *possible*, but often not easy if you are not experienced with these things. It would be a lot easier to use a USB hub.

Comment: Yes.  I've used laptops with no working USB drives & no CD/DVD trays for QA-testing by modifying the installed OSes boot loader to offer ISOs installed on the drive for option on boot.   It was a pain; but allowed me to QA-test (*Quality Assurance*) using devices that would have otherwise been useless for that purpose. Once setup (*a pain*) it became less of a pain; but the initial setup (you'll need to do) maybe easy or like some of mine - a pain.

Comment: Keep in mind that Ubuntu is not designed to run on faulty/broken hardware, nor to compensate for faulty/broken hardware, so your experience may be less than you hope for.