# How to download Ubuntu dual boot on mac no usb

Tags: system-installation

I have a macOS catalina, memory of 3gb, 250gb storage, 2012 macbook pro, how do i install Ubuntu without usb or cd?If you are wondering, i dont and cant have usb or cd.
Thanks for any insturctions and any help
(sorry for any bad english)

Comment: 3GB of RAM will not be enough for the standard Ubuntu installation, but you may be able to use Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. That aside, are you planning on replacing Catalina? Or would you like to dual-boot between MacOS and Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb)

Comment: i would like to dual boot, as said in title

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you need to install Windows before...

1. Organize the partitions by separating them into parts, starting with a partition with some background.. A Hard disk, for example, should be separated into its portions.
   The second step is to install the system. Reboot into Windows. Unetbootin may prompt you to uninstall the installation….
   In Step 3, you will need to remove Windows and restart it.

Look at this guide: https://www.systranbox.com/how-to-install-linux-on-macbook-pro-without-usb/