# Upgrading Directly from Ubuntu 10.04 to 22.10?

Tags: upgrade

I have a quite old machine lying around which is capable of doing daily work like YouTube videos and casual web surfing.

It has Windows installation which has become laggy.

I am thinking of installing Ubuntu on it. The problem is I don't have any spare USB drive to make bootable USB of latest version. But, I have Ubuntu CD that was provided during ShipIt program like 10+ years back and I think it has Ubuntu 10.04 version on it.

So, if I install Ubuntu through that CD, will I be able to upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu i.e. 22.10 over the internet?

Comment: A short answer is no. 10.04 is too old for that. And don't expect Ubuntu 22.10 will work better on an old hardware.

Comment: How are we to interpret what you mean by an *quite old machine lying around*... I use hardware from 2005 in *Quality Assurance* testing of current Ubuntu products/released; but the oldest hardware I use is from 2003...   Yours is '*lying around*' which may mean its even older?  (*you also mention 10.04 so it maybe 586 class as 686 wasn't yet mandated for Ubuntu installs*), but 586 class computers (*in Linux terms*) are no longer supported (686 being the last supported with Ubuntu until *disco* or 19.04 reached EOL). We can't possibly know what you mean by *quite old* thus cannot currently know

Comment: Another thought...   I used to use old *thinkpads* that didn't have working USB ports in QA; where I downloaded the ISO to a partition which had another OS on it; and then modify the bootloader (via script) which added the ISOs to the boot loader options...   By then rebooting I could boot ISOs on disk, and do QA-test installs to other portions of the disk.  The details to achieve this are documented on this web site; however it's many times the amount of effort/work/skill needed compared to writing an ISO to media & booting from that.. so it's possible, however 10.04 is still off-topic here

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.    Yes there are exceptions where you want to *release-upgrade* to a supported release; but 10.04 had to upgrade options; to the next release (or 10.10) or the next LTS which was 12.04; and those options disappeared when those releases reached EOL

Comment: "*The problem is I don't have any spare USB drive*" Borrow one from a friend. Ask around; folks have them. Trying to install and then release-upgrading *six times* will take you literally all day...if it works at all.

Comment: Will the computer boot in UEFI mode? Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1417942/43926