# Why can't installation of Ubuntu be done without a USB drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb

Why can't installation of Ubuntu be done without a USB drive?

I recently was trying to dual-boot Ubuntu on my older desktop that is currently running Windows 11.  I tried with a USB drive, and (after several attempts) the Ubuntu screen appeared but then just went blank.  I tried tweaking the BIOS, but several more attempts did not get me anywhere.  I then tried UNetbootin, but still was unsuccessful.

So, I instead decided to try VMware Workstation.  Installing Ubuntu was quite easy, and no USB drives were needed.  I just downloaded an iso and started VMware.  Presto: Ubuntu was successfully installed on the VM.

So, my question is this: why can't we install Linux on a hard-drive partition as easily as we can install it using VM software?  And without the need of using USB drives?

Is it possible to create software similar to VMware that would install Linux from an iso directly onto a hard-drive partition instead of on a VM?

This is not an urgent matter.  I am fine with using VM.  But I am rather curious to hear what you tech gurus have to say about this.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release or Ubuntu product details; but I've performed many installs (inc. QA-test installs) without using thumb-drive, using ISOs stored on drives (*on boxes without working USB ports mostly*), from DVD or *optical* media etc....   USB thumb-drives are not necessary for most Ubuntu products/releases.   In effect you can use any media your boxes/devices will boot from (*including CF-flash & other media; though I've not used those types of media for a long time as USB-drives are just easier*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb) You actually can... FYI, VM stands for **virtual machine**. The hardware is virtualized, including removable media like USB and optical media. The reason you need installation media on bare metal is because you can't virtualize a USB drive. Nor can you have a preconfigured one-size-fits all image. VM images can be identical for everyone using the VM software. The Ubuntu installer for your PC has to work on everyone else's PC too.

Comment: There is a very clear and thorough [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) that walks you through every single step. You just need to follow along. The only thing you need to figure out on your own is how to access a boot menu to boot the USB on your particular computer. Most motherboards tell you how to do this every single time you turn on your computer. If not, look it up!  Everything else is completely prescriptive step-by-step in the tutorial. If this is still too difficult, it's probably best if you don't bother trying the link I posted above.

Comment: You need to turn of fast boot in Windows. You need to turn of TPM and Secure boot in UEFI ( what some people still but incorrectly call BIOS ) to install Ubuntu. You can install Ubuntu ( or another .iso ) if you install e.g. Grub2Win and make it your primairy bootloader. You need to add the option to boot from .iso in the bootmenu.

Comment: My question was answered in a previous post by C. S. Cameron:  Boot Ubuntu on Windows UEFI computer without USB or DVD.  
Use Windows Disk Management to create FAT32 partition 3GB or larger.
Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to new partition.
Reboot pressing F12 and select UEFI Ubuntu.
C.S. Cameron  -- Thanks, CS!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  A simple and elegant solution!  And it worked for me.