# I have an error updating from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, updates, 22.04

I tried updating my linux as described here: https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-22-04 , but It returns [this Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL7ux.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: How did you damage your python?  `python --version` and `python3 --version` Please [edit] your question to add the output. And please no picture.

Comment: @nobody I didn't damage my python. Its a freshly setted up machine

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix this, but I do know a workaround.

1. Make a comprehensive list of all the packages (software) you've installed.
2. Make a copy of your home directory(ies).
3. Install the new version from scratch.
4. Copy your home directory back.
5. Reinstall the packages.

Comment: I cannot make this, because for some reason my hoster doesn't give me the option to install Ubuntu 22

Comment: "Hoster"?  What are you trying to install on?

Comment: I mean my hosting service. In their web panel you dont have an option for Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: So . . . you're trying to install on a virtual machine?

Comment: no, it's a dedicated server

Comment: I'm not that familiar with that configuration, but perhaps the general instructions here would help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb