# How to install Ubuntu from a partition in hard drive without using USB stick or DVD

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a new laptop HP Victus FB0013NV which comes with preintalled Win11. I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows in order to have a dual boot system.

I have tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb) where it basically creates a fat partition to simulate a USB drive (I do not have over 4GB drive to use) and "burn" an Ubuntu iso image in it.

Theoretically, when I boot I should be able to choose the Ubuntu partition and boot into a live Ubuntu environment from where I could install Ubuntu in my machine. Although I am able to reach the part where it says to choose a EFI (I think) file to boot from, the only option I get is the windows one. So, I virtually reboot and reboot to the same win11 environment.

I have also tried [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/484456/546065) but there wasn't any difference.

Is there a way to make my system see the Ubuntu partition? Should I create a UEFI menu somehow?

Alternatively, to make the Ubuntu fit in my 4GB drive (I think it's a bit above this) could I copy some files but not all of them? For example I see that `pool\restricted` takes 1.53GB. Could I omit some packages in here without causing the ububtu system to break? I could for example install them afterwards I imagine.

Comment: I use & like Kubuntu and 22.04.1 was 3.5GB. You have to extract ISO into FAT32 partition and move boot flag to that partition so UEFI boots from it. But if any issue, you may not be able to boot. Make sure you have both a Windows repair/recovery flash drive (its needs larger flash drive, and an Ubuntu live installer flash drive. Also you really need a full backup of Windows as any system change has some risks. I now like external SSDs as they are almost as fast as internal SSDs and are not that expensive now. I used a M.2 SSD & M.2/USB adapter. New system may need 23.04 to have latest kernel.

Comment: Well, for Ubuntu it was larger than 4G so it was an issue.

Comment: You can download and install the server, and then install the desktop of your choice from the command line. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` Or during server install choose desktop. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel