# Error while installing Ubuntu without CD and USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm not sure if I killed two flash drives while trying to install ubuntu or they were already damaged but I'm out of flash drives so I tried installing ubuntu without usb using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357348). I followed the steps and I could see the options in boot menu- try or install ubuntu etc. But when I click on them, i get an error saying "unable to find a medium containing a live file system".

Any ideas how to solve this?

PC Specs: Dell Inspiron 5000, i7, 32gb, 512gb ssd

Comment: Ubuntu does not kill flash drives more than any other usage. Seems like you encountered a rare coincidence.

Comment: @user535733 Oh okay. Flashing iso file to usb drive is same as copying files?