# can you install ubuntu on a sign m 15 laptop?

Tags: boot, usb-drive

i can find no way to boot off a stick memory on this machine.  it has win 11 on it and apparantly keeps a copy in the bios because you can reinstall windows.  i want to put ubuntu 22 or maybe 24 on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb)

Comment: Do note that Ubuntu Core 22 is a *snap* only product of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server; ie. the 22 is a *reduced* version of 22.04 that has features taken out making it smaller & better for IoT or Cloud use; the 22.04 product is fully-featured. Ubuntu 24.04 isn't expected to be releases until 2024-April (why it's 24.04) with 24 expected 2-3 months after that, so it won't be available for longer (24 is expected to be the first version of Ubuntu Core that can be used with a GUI/Desktop too).

Comment: Install:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview & https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview Windows keeps the Product key in UEFI, so you can reinstall it in UEFI boot mode.